# JQuery autocomplete - How do I control list based on nearby DOM elements without using id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is in JQuery, using the JQuery-UI version of autocomplete

I'm in a bit of an edge case.  I'm working inside a form that must be indefinitely cloneable, so I can't use id tags for unique identification, and I can't just search down from the top to find something that looks like the DOM elements I'm working with - I have to use relative functions (.closest, .find, and so forth).  Inside this form, I have a setup with a country field, a state field, and a location field, and the location field is supposed to be an autocomplete, fed from a link, where it hands the current value of the country and state fields on the link going up for server-side filtering.  I'd *like* it to go something like this:

```
function locPrep(locNode) {
  $locNode.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $locDiv = $(this).closest("div.locWrapper");
      $stateNode = $locDiv.find("input.state");
      $countryNode = $locDiv.find("input.country");
      $.post("/FormHost/AutocompleteLocList",
        {state:$stateNode.val(), country:$countryNode.val(), term:request.term },
        function (data) {
          response(data);
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

...except that that doesn't work because the $(this) for the source function isn't locNode, and I can't just declare it outside and use it inside because locPrep gets called repeatedly, once for each autofill in the form.  If I try that, the fact that Jquery makes everything global causes all of the autofills in the form to reference the country and state fields for the last one. I tried using javascript vars to get around the scoping issues and it broke strangely.  Can anyone help?

---

Edit: thanks to Dmitriy Naumov's kind assistance, I was able to hammer together a functioning solution (though I'm still not entirely sure *why* it works, given some of the things that I tried that did not).  I'm including the functioning code in the hopes that it may help someone else later. (I've certainly gained quite a lot from the answered questions of others.)

First, I went through and changed every instance where I called the function from "locPrep(foo);" to "new locPrep(foo);"  I also changed it to take locDiv rather than locNode.  Then, I changed the code to the following (though this is, as that was, a somewhat simplified version).

```
function locPrep(locDiv) {
  $locNode = $(locDiv).find("input.locationAutofill")
  $locNode.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      var stateVar = $(locDiv).find("input.state").val();
      var countryVar = $(locDiv).find("input.country").val();
      $.post("/FormHost/AutocompleteLocList",
        {state:stateVar, country:countryVar, term:request.term },
        function (data) {
          response(data);
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

I'm not entirely sure which bits of this were necessary, but as a group they manhandle the code around to using tight enough scoping to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save $(this) to a variable and pass it as a parameter (locNode) to your function (during initialization). Also, instead of $(this) you can pass a link to the container element, so each of your initialized autocompletes will know its parent.

**Update:** The following may not be 100% correct in terms of autocomplete initialization, but its a solid illustration how to create **2 unique instances of locPrep** in `<div id="myDiv1">`  and  `<div id="myDiv2">`

```
myContainer1 = $('#myDiv1');
myContainer2 = $('#myDiv2');

myAutocompleteInstance1 = new locPrep(myContainer1);
myAutocompleteInstance2 = new locPrep(myContainer2);
```

**Update2**: how to pass **this**

```
function locPrep(locNode, currentThis) {

 /// use currentThis instead of $(this) inside locPrep function

  $locNode.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $locDiv = currentThis.closest("div.locWrapper");
      $stateNode = $locDiv.find("input.state");
      $countryNode = $locDiv.find("input.country");
      $.post("/FormHost/AutocompleteLocList",
        {state:$stateNode.val(), country:$countryNode.val(), term:request.term },
        function (data) {
          response(data);
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

**init:**

```
myAutocompleteInstance1 = new locPrep(myContainer1, $(this));
```

**new** will make sure that value of currentThis is unique in each instance of locPrep

Comment: That sounds promising, but I've not seen anywhere how to add another parameter to functions (like the source function, above) that are themselves passed in as parameters to other functions.  It had seemed from reading the documentation that the function interface in this case was pretty much set.  If there's a technique that I'm missing here, I'd be delighted to hear about it.

Comment: @Ben Barden: please see my update. It illustrates how you can pass container link to locPrep. locPrep will treat each link the same way (as a locNode)

Comment: Okay... I think I'm maybe understanding about a third of what I need to to get what you're saying.  I tried newing the outer function by itself, in case that's what you meant - it did nothing to prevent the inherent global scoping of Jquery objects.  I googled a bit based on what you'd said and came across some stuff about object oriented javascript, with functions as classes.  It's conceivable that that might work, predefining the function and then passing it in, but it looks tenuous, and if that's not what you mean, I don't want to waste a bunch of time finding out that it *doesn't* work.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Javascript is not 100% object oriented, but you can still code semi-OOP style. The main point of it all is that myAutocompleteInstance1.locNode and myAutocompleteInstance1.locNode will have different values after the described initialization, i.e. each Autocomplete will know its parent. Isn't that what you need ?

Comment: The autocompletes do know their parents.  The locNode that gets passed in as a Jquery object is the parent, and I can use it inside the autocomplete function call just fine.  Where I can't use it is inside the function (request, response) definition.  I haven't been able to figure out a way to pass it in as a (this), and trying to access it as a global doesn't work because it runs when the user types into the field.  If the user has created any more autocomplete fields in the meantime (and thus run locPrep on them) the Jquery objects change to fit the newest field - only the last one works.

Comment: Well, I took what you said, went back and hammered on it a few more times and it works.  I feel like it's held together with chewing gum and black magic, but it works.  Thank you very much, Sir.